# sql query result in null.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm pretty new to php and really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My variable $largeid appears to be empty in the result:

```
$newfile=$_POST['largeName'].$largeid.".php";
```

Even after executing this code:

```
while($largeidrow = mysql_fetch_array(largeidresult))
{
    $largeid = $largeidrow['large_id'];
}
```

This is the whole code:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO larges(name,largecontent)VALUES('$_POST[largeName]','$_POST[content]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
    echo "failed";
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

$largeidresult = ("SELECT large_id FROM larges WHERE name='$_POST[largeName]'");

if (!mysql_query($largeidresult,$con))
{
    echo "failed";
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($largeidrow = mysql_fetch_array(largeidresult))
{
    $largeid = $largeidrow['large_id'];
}

if ($_POST['largeName']) {
error_reporting(0);
$i=1;
while($file = fopen("untitled$i.php", "r")) { fclose($file); $i++; }
if($file = fopen("untitled$i.php", "w")) {
$php = "<html> \n <head> \n </head> \n <body> \n test \n <?php \n echo 'hallo'; \n ?>     \n </body> \n <html>";
    $file_ext = strip_tags($_POST['$php']);
if(fwrite($file, $php) === false) { echo "Could not write"; exit; }
fclose($file);
$newfile=$_POST['largeName'].$largeid.".php";
system("mv untitled$i.php $newfile");
header("Location: $newfile");
}
}
else {
echo "<form method=post action='".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."'>\n";
echo "New File Name: <input name='filename'>\n</form>\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'll say *Do not use mysql functions*. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

[From PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> Warning This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be
>   removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension
>   should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ
>   for more information. Alternatives to this function include..

In your code, the way you're calling `mysql_fetch_array(#link)` is wrong.

```
$sql = ("SELECT large_id FROM larges WHERE name='$_POST[largeName]'");

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result)
 {
   while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $largeid = $row['large_id'];
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make that insert you are using this line :

```
$sql="INSERT INTO larges(name,largecontent)VALUES('$_POST[largeName]','$_POST[content]')";
```

Change it with this one:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO larges(name,largecontent)VALUES('".$_POST[largeName]."','".$_POST[content]."')";
```

You must separate php variables from static text. Use the same method for your SELECT too.